# expose docker container's application url to host

Tags: docker

I have a docker image with some ruby on rails environment built in (i.e. installing some rails gems and system packages) and I have an `EXPOSE 3000` to expose the port at the end.

I ran a container with `docker run -p 3000:3000 -ti <image> bash`, then start the rails server. The logs are saying the web server is available on `localhost:3000`. I tried to connect to both the `IPAddress` as specified in `docker inspect <id>` and `localhost` on my host machine, but neither would be able to connect. What could be the problem here?

Comment: You cannot access a service if it is bound to `localhost` inside the container. You will need to modify the service configuration to bind to `0.0.0.0` (the "all" address), then you will be able to use the published ports on your host (or the container ip).

Comment: how do I modify service configuration? Do you have an example or doc

Comment: That depends entirely on what application you're running...so, no, I am unable to provide you with an example. Typically you will be looking for something like a "bind" or "listen" address. If you edit your question to provide us with a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it's more likely that we can help you out.

Comment: I updated my question.. hope it's provides enough information now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your application is listening on `localhost`, it will only respond to requests from the container's localhost - that is, other processes inside the container.

To fix this you need to set the listen address of your server to listen to any address (usually, you specify this as 0.0.0.0). I've never used rails, but from a quick search, [you should use the `-b` option](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#bin-rails-server).

So changing your `ENTRYPOINT` or `CMD` in your Dockerfile to contain `-b 0.0.0.0` would probably do it.

Comment: Thanks. setting it to run on `0.0.0.0` is the fix here

Comment: Good to know it helped! If it resolved your question, please accept the answer.